# Uploading fire to Firebase Storage using firebase-admin in Node

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I need to upload a file from a Node script to my Firebase storage using `firebase-admin`.

This is how I'm **doing in the browser: (IT WORKS)**

```
// THIS IS INSIDE A FUNCTION
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('my-images/' + fileName);
const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file,metadata);
```

This is how I'm **TRYING to do in the Node script:**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// THIS IS INSIDE A FUNCTION
const storageRef = admin.storage().ref('my-images/' + fileName);
const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file,metadata);
```

And I'm getting the **error:**

```
TypeError: admin.storage(...).ref is not a function
```

**I also tried:**

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: "MY_BUCKET.appspot.com"
});

// THIS IS INSIDE A FUNCTION
const storageRef = admin.storage().bucket().ref('my-images/' + fileName);
const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file,metadata);
```

And I'm getting the **error:**

```
TypeError: admin.storage(...).bucket(...).ref is not a function
```

**QUESTION**

I need to save the file in my default bucket inside the `my-images` folder. What is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [Google Cloud Storage Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/index.html) you need to use a different approach compare to the JavaScript SDK.

More precisely, you need to use the [`upload()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) method of a [`Bucket`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html), as follows:

```
bucket.upload('my-images/' + fileName).then(function(data) {
  const file = data[0];
});
```

You will find more example in the documentation (link above)

Comment: Thanks! The DOC specifies that the `upload` method requires a `pathString TYPE string` which it's described as _"The fully qualified path to the file you wish to upload to your bucket."_ Does it mean that the file needs to be saved in my file system? Can't I use a file (a Blob, a Buffer, a Uint8Array) from a variable from the script? I'm asking this because I'm downloading the file from another source before uploading it.

Comment: In this case, if I am not mistaking, you might use [`createWriteStream()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream) method of a File.

Comment: You are right. `createWriteStream()` does the job! I've tested it and it works. Thanks!